# Is there a provably optimal block (piece) size for torrents (and individual files)?

Tags: rsync, file-transfer, bittorrent

The BitTorrent [protocol](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html#info-dictionary) doesn't specify block (piece) size. This is left to the user. (I've seen different torrents for the same content with 3 or more different choices.)

I'm thinking of filing a [BitTorrent Enhancement Proposal](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0000.html) which needs to make a specific block size mandatory — both for the whole torrent, and also for individual files (for which [BTv2 (BEP 52)](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0052.html#file-tree-layout) specifies bs=16KiB).

The only thing I've found that's close is the rsync block size algorithm in [Tridgell & Mackerras' technical paper](https://andrew.cmu.edu/course/15-749/READINGS/required/cas/tridgell96.pdf). Their bs=300-1100 B (# bytes aren't powers of 2).

Torrents, however, [usually](https://wiki.vuze.com/w/Torrent_Piece_Size) [use](https://web.archive.org/web/20201028050446/https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification) bs=64kB–16MB (# bytes are powers of 2, and much larger than rsync's) for the whole torrent (and, for BTv2, 16KiB for files).

The specified block size doesn't need to be a constant. It could be a function of thing-hashed size, of course (like it is in rsync). It could also be a function of file type; e.g. there might be some block sizes which are better for making partial video/archive/etc files more usable.

See also [this analysis of BitTorrent as a block-aligned file system](https://blog.libtorrent.org/2014/12/a-bittorrent-filesystem/).

So…

1. What are optimal block sizes for a torrent, generic file, or partial usefulness of specific file types?
2. Where did the 16KiB bs in BEP 52 come from?

Answer (score 7):

Block and piece size are not the same thing.

A piece is the unit that is hashed into the `pieces` string in v1 torrents, one hash per piece.

A block is a part of a piece that is requested via request (ID 6) and delivered via piece (ID 7) messages. These messages basically consist of `(piece number, offset, length)` tuple where the length is the block size. In this sense blocks are very ephemeral constructs in v1 torrents but they are still important since downloading clients have to keep a lot of state about them in memory. Since the downloading client is in control of the request size they customarily use fixed 16KiB blocks, even though they could do this more flexibly. For an uploading client it does not really matter complexity-wise as they have to simply serve the bytes covered by `(piece,offset,length)` and keep no further state.
Since clients generally implement an upper message size limit to avoid DoS attacks 16KiB is also the recommended upper bound. Specialized implementations could use larger blocks, but for public torrents that doesn't really happen.

For v2 torrents the picture changes a bit. There now are three concepts

- the ephemeral blocks sent via messages
- the pieces (now representing some layer in the merkle tree), needed for v1 compatibility in hybrid torrents and also stored as `piece layers` outside the info dictionary to allow partial file resume
- the leaf blocks of the merkle tree

The first type is essentially unchanged compared to v1 torrents but the incentive to use 16KiB-sized blocks is much stronger now because that is also the leaf hash size.

The piece size must now be a power of two and multiple of 16KiB, this constraint did not exist in v1 torrents.

The leaf block size is fixed to 16KiB, it is relevant when constructing the merkle tree and exchanging message IDs 21 (hash request) and 22 (hashes)

> What are optimal block sizes for a torrent, generic file, or partial usefulness of specific file types?

For a v1 torrent the piece size combined with the file sizes determines a lower bound of the metadata (aka `.torrent` file) size. Each piece must be stored as a 20byte hash in `pieces`, thus larger pieces result in fewer hashes and smaller `.torrent` files. For terabyte-scale torrents a 16KiB piece size result in a ~1GB torrent file, which is unacceptable for most use-cases.

For a v2 torrent it would result in a similarly sized `piece layers` in the root dictionary. Or if a client does not have the `piece layers` data available (e.g. because they started a download via infohash) they will have to retrieve the data via hash request messages instead, ultimately resulting in the same overhead, albeit more spread out over the course of the download.

> Where did the 16KiB bs in BEP 52 come from?

16KiB was already the de-facto block size for most clients. Since a merkle-tree must be calculated from some leaf hashes a fixed block size for those leaves had to be defined. Hence the established messaging block size was also chosen for the merkle tree blocks.

> The only thing I've found that's close is the rsync block size algorithm in Tridgell & Mackerras' technical paper. Their bs=300-1100 B (# bytes aren't powers of 2).

rsync uses a [rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) for content-aware chunking rather than fixed-size blocks and that is the primary driver for their chunk-size choices. So rsync considerations do not apply to bittorrent.